# Making Android image larger when pressed, and normal when released

Tags: android, xml, image, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have an app, that has an ImageViev, which can be clicked to perform an action. I want it to be a little bit bigger when it's pressed, and go back to normal when it's released. The problem is, I have 10 different images that appear in the ImageViev, depending on the situation. I've read a lot of threads about that, and none of the solutions seems to solve my problem. I need to:

- Make an image bigger when the button is pressed, or replace it with a bigger version.
- Make the image shrink when the button is released, or go back to normal version of the image.
- When I change the image in the ImageView, it will still change its size when pressed.

I've tried this so far:

- Creating a drawable item, that looks like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/b1big" />
  <item
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/b1"/>
  </selector>
  ```

but it won't work, because Android automatically scales the image to the size of the ImageView, so no matter if b1big is bigger than b1.

- Changing the width and height of the drawable item, but it doesn't have these parameters.

Is creating 10 normal images like image1, image2... image10, then creating 10 big images like image1big... image10big and then creating 10 drawable objects like:

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image1big" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image1"/>
```

and using them as src for my ImageView? How do I prevent them from scaling then?

Comment: Why dont you try this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Comment: Did you set `android:scaleType = "center"` property for your `ImageView`?

Comment: If the doesn't need to overlap adjacent views and doesn't need to increase in size that much you could give it a padding of x pixels when in the normal state and 0 pixels when pressed

Comment: @WISHY your answer might be right, but it is a little bit too complex, as the program I am writing is very simple. Also, I need to make the image go back to normal immediately after it is released, not after the second tap.

Comment: @electrocrat I did it, didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you trying to make a personal photography app? Have you tried Grid View and image View? You would need to make an array to store your images in your java code, and instantiate your UI controls then make an grid.image adapter and an onclick function. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Update you selector's content to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/b1big" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/b1"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't help